# Get width from element using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my html:

```
<div class="bar no" style="width: 25.0916%;"></div>
```

I'd like to access the width size as a number or percentage.

I've tried some the following but the first returns nothing and the second returns the number in pixels.

```
width = this.getBBox().width

width = d3.select(this).style("width")
```

What can I use to return 500 or 25.0%?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compare the following:

```js
console.log('Computed style width as pixels: ');
console.log(d3.select('.bar').style('width'));
console.log('Computed style width as a number: ');
console.log(parseFloat(d3.select('.bar').style('width')));
console.log('As a percent: ');
console.log(d3.select('.bar').node().style.width);
console.log('Actual width as number: ');
console.log(d3.select('.bar').node().offsetWidth);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div class="bar no" style="width: 25.0916%;"></div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there a reason you are doing the awkward `document.write()` instead of using `console.log()` to print to the snippet's console emulation? Good answer, BTW ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus, no reason.  Just screwing around.  I originally was going to color code things.

Comment: Holy moly! When I posted my first comment, I thought the use of `document.write()` was, well,... not *that* good. But changing the URL to a protocol-agnostic one takes it one step further ;-) Isn't that considered an anti-pattern nowadays? https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/, https://jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url. Could you do the color coding for me, please ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus, are you watching this 9 month old post for changes?  I'll edit again to make you happy :)