# Keep Treemap inside bootstrap div

Tags: d3.js, bootstrap-grid

How can I get my treemap to fit to stay inside a bootstrap div tag. I have 2 bootsrap row classes. The top one with a 2 columns and the bottom one with 1 column. It can be seen in this gist.

https://bl.ocks.org/centem/81945b90ca4c20da27c54dd89e9acebe

Answer (score 0):

1. Use overflow-x : scroll // this will add scroll bar to map and div won't 
   overlfow the page
2. Create the SVG based on the current width // get width of the parent and 
   render graph based on that

Comment: Thank you for responding Umesh. But, the parent div doesn't have a width set.

Comment: @charlie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922149/get-width-from-element-using-d3-js#answer-40922248

Comment: Thanks Umesh I was able to get the width using console.log(d3.select('.container').style('width')) from the post you mention. But, why does it seem to sit outside the bootstrap col? I'm trying to get it to sit inside the bootstrap col.

Comment: Change #treemap height to 300px.